# Solving an inequality involving exponentials

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals, logarithms, exponentiation

For a homework problem, I'm supposed to compute the integral of $f(x) = x e^{-x^2}$, which I did, and got a result of $F(x) = -\frac{1}{2} e^{-x^2} + C$.

Secondly, I'm supposed to find the smallest value of N such that the area under the graph $f(x)$ between N and N+1 is, at most, 0.01.

From that problem description, I came up with the following inequality:

$$
-\frac{1}{2}[e^{-(N+1)^2} - e^{-N^2}] \leq 0.01
$$

Which I then changed to:

$$
\frac{1}{2}[e^{-N^2} - e^{-(N+1)^2}] \leq 0.01
$$

Multiplying both sides by 2, I get:

$$
e^{-N^2} - e^{-(N+1)^2} \leq 0.02
$$

However, I'm stumped at this point. I was able to play around with the equation in Desmos and get N=2, which satisfies the inequality, but that's hardly a good solution.

How do I solve the above inequality analytically? Any pointers on the next steps I should take? Is trying to solve via the inequality even the correct approach?

Textbook: OpenStax Calculus Volume 1

Section: 5.6

Exercise: 377, Page 606 (Note that the problem erroneously states the upper bound to be N+10 instead of N+1)

Comment: It seems they are only considering natural numbers, which can be done through guess-and-check with some basic intuition.

Answer (score 1):

Making the problem more general with $x$ instead of $n$, you are looking for the zero of function
$$f(x)=e^{-x^2} - e^{-(x+1)^2}-\epsilon$$ where $\epsilon$ is a small number. If $x$ is supposed to be large, since
$$e^{-x^2} - e^{-(x+1)^2}=e^{-x^2}\left(1-e^{-(2x+1) } \right)\sim e^{-x^2}$$ and an *estimate* of the solution is
$$x_0=\sqrt{-\log (\epsilon )}$$ Now, since $f(x)$ varies very fast, consider instead that you look for the zero of
$$g(x)=\log\left(e^{-x^2} - e^{-(x+1)^2} \right)-\log(\epsilon )$$ and use Newton method with
$$g'(x)=\frac{2-2 \left(e^{2 x+1}-1\right) x}{e^{2 x+1}-1}$$

For illustration, let us try with $\epsilon=10^{-2}$. This would give the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 2.145966026289347239636184 \\
 1 & 2.144787850787186005128209 \\
 2 & 2.144787523122507226762567 \\
 3 & 2.144787523122481882718073
\end{array}
\right)$$